# Dividing DataFrame Groups by another DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrameas below:

```
Tester = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                       'Col2': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                       'Col3': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                       'Col4': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                       'Col5': [1, 1, 2, 2]})
```

I would like to group the DataFrame by Col1 and then divide the group by an equally sized DataFrame containing scalars:

```
Divider = pd.DataFrame({'Col2': [2, 2],
                       'Col3': [2, 2],
                       'Col4': [2, 2],
                       'Col5': [2, 2]})
```

In my mind it would work something like:

```
df = Tester.groupby('Col1').div(Divider)
```

But that returns an error. Any ideas on how this could be done? I would expect the following output DataFrame:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                       'Col2': [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1],
                       'Col3': [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1],
                       'Col4': [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1],
                       'Col5': [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1]})
```

**Note** that each group `A`, `B`, etc. would have the same dimension as the dividing DataFrame `Divider` (2x4 in this instance)

Comment: You example is a bit ambiguous, can you use non-identical numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `cumcount()`

```
df.set_index([df.groupby('Col1').cumcount(),'Col1']).div(df2,level=0).reset_index(level=1)
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0    A   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
1    A   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
0    B   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
1    B   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) and divide each group by the divider as a numpy array:

```
cols = Divider.columns
div = Divider.to_numpy()

Tester[cols] = Tester.groupby('Col1')[cols].apply(lambda g: g/div)
```

Or using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) and **assuming the groups are sorted**:

```
cols = Divider.columns

Tester[cols] /= np.repeat(Divider.to_numpy(), Tester['Col1'].nunique(), axis=0)
```

If the groups are not sorted:

```
cols = Divider.columns

Tester[cols] = (Tester.sort_values(by='Col1')[cols]
                / np.repeat(Divider.to_numpy(), Tester['Col1'].nunique(), axis=0)
               )
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0    A   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
1    A   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
2    B   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
3    B   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
```

Comment: How would you adjust this if the divide DataFrame was [1,2], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2]?

Comment: @Jack adjust how? the issue with your examples is that they are ambiguous. I actually undertood the question fully differently in my initial attempt to answer. Please craft a meaningful example with non-ambiguous numbers (a random input might be nice). Unless I misunderstood the question, you shouldn't need to change anything, my code is supposed to work in all cases.